# Gwt Controller With Annotation Approach

Tags: java, spring, gwt, spring-mvc, gwt-rpc

I already integrated GWT with Spring MVC by implementing the Controller which is called
by DispatcherServlet using SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.

```
public class GwtRpcController extends RemoteServiceServlet implements Controller,
        ServletContextAware {
        @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        super.doPost(request, response);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to use the new approach with the annotation `@Controller`, like below:

```
@Controller
public class GwtRpcController extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        ServletContextAware {

}
```

In this case there will be no handleRequest method, where should I do `super.doPost(request, response);` ?

Answer (score 0):

See [annotated web mvc controllers in spring 2.5](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/11/14/annotated-web-mvc-controllers-in-spring-25/)

You should not to do doPost/doGet manually, just define controller method with corresponding parameters, return value and annonations for url mapping.

Comment: I am using the Controller only for integrating GWT and Spring. The controller calls the related RemoteServiceServlet Impl like in the link:  (http://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/giving-gwt-a-spring-in-its-step) I need the controller behave like GWT's RemoteServiceServlet when doPost or somehow.